# Android-Tumblr API - Jumblr for Android [OAuthConnectionException]

Tags: android, oauth, tumblr

I realized that Jumblr, a Tumblr APi for Android isn't well documented on how do we actually go about implementing one. I've successfully authorize my account on my app. That's all. According to Jumblr's README https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr, all you have to do is to

```
 JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient("consumer_key","consumer_secret");
 client.setToken("oauth_toke n", "oauth_token_secret");
```

where consumer key and secret is already set in my app and oauth_token and token_secret is got by the app when user logs in.However, I'm getting errors like

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.Full logcat:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does the log give any more information?

Comment: @mikedidthis: Thanks for comment. I already solve the problem :D

Comment: Excellent. If the solution is worthy, maybe post it as an answer for others to learn from?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.It works for me. Use  AsyncTask. Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ExportDatabaseCSVTask t=new ExportDatabaseCSVTask();
    t.execute("");


}

public class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
 { 
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    User user;
    JumblrClient client;
    String a,b,c;
    int d,e;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    { 
        this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting Info...");
        this.dialog.show();

         client = new JumblrClient("consumer_key","consumer_secret");
         client.setToken("oauth_token","oauth_token_secret");

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args)
    {

        user = client.user();
        // Make the request  
        a =  user.getName();
        b = user.getDefaultPostFormat();  
        c = user.toString();  
        d= user.getFollowingCount();  
        e = user.getLikeCount();  

        List<Blog> blogs = client.userFollowing();
        for (Blog blog : blogs) {
            Log.e("USER","1"+blog.getTitle());
        }

        TextPost post;
        try {
            post = client.newPost(client.user().getName(), TextPost.class);
            post.setTitle("title");
            post.setBody("body");
            post.save();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) 
    {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing())
        {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        } 

        if(success )
        {
            Log.e("USER", "" + a);  
              Log.e("USER", "" +b);  
              Log.e("USER", "" + c);  
              Log.e("USER", "" + d);  
              Log.e("USER", "" + e);  

        }




    }
} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, I am using above code but its not working, Its giving an error of no class found 04-23 10:36:34.606: E/AndroidRuntime(847): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.scribe.builder.api.TumblrApi
04-23 10:36:34.606: E/AndroidRuntime(847):  at com.tumblr.jumblr.request.RequestBuilder.setConsumer(RequestBuilder.java:120)

Answer (score 0):

Create a user token from following link:
https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info

You can use 
  client.setToken("oauth_token","oauth_token_secret");